Bind socket to interface using bind() v using setsockopt()
We run code inside an [Ubuntu] Docker container, as part of a test system, which needs to open a socket on a specific interface (ppp0, created through pppd by the device under test), rather than sneaking it out through eth0.
When this Docker container is run under Raspbian, setsockopt() does the trick, i.e. this works:
struct ifreq interface = {0};
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);

snprintf(interface.ifr_name, sizeof(interface.ifr_name), "ppp0");
if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE,
               &interface, sizeof(interface)) == 0) {
    // Things routed through sock() appear on ppp0
...

Running the same Docker container under Centos8 doesn't give sufficient permissions (setsockopt() returns -1 and errno is EPERM), so I would like to use the alternative method suggested in this answer, employing bind() instead.
However, I can't make that work (see code below): bind() returns zero but activity on the bound socket does not result in traffic on ppp0, or anywhere else that I can find (i.e. not eth0 either); this also run on Docker-on-Raspbian so that I can flip between the success and fail cases.
Can anyone spot my [deliberate :-)] mistake?
struct sockaddr_in bindAddress = {0};
struct ifaddrs *pInterfaceAddresses = NULL;
struct ifaddrs *pTmp;
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);

bindAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
if (getifaddrs(&pInterfaceAddresses) == 0) {
    pTmp = pInterfaceAddresses;
    while ((pTmp != NULL) && (bindAddress.sin_addr.s_addr == 0)) {
        if ((strcmp(pTmp->ifa_name, "ppp0") == 0) && 
            (pTmp->ifa_addr != NULL) &&
            (pTmp->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET)) {
            bindAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *) pTmp->ifa_addr)->sin_addr.s_addr;
        }
        pTmp = pTmp->ifa_next;
    }
    freeifaddrs(pInterfaceAddresses);
}

if (bindAddress.sin_addr.s_addr != 0) {
    // bind() returns zero but sock goes nowhere
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &bindAddress, sizeof(bindAddress));
}


What happens if you bind to INADDR_ANY?

The address you specify in bind() is address you accept incoming requests on. It has nothing to do with the interface used for outgoing messages. Unless you use SO_BINDTODEVICE, outgoing packets are routed to an interface based on the destination address.

Aha, that would explain it.  Darn.  I guess my question now is how I can modify the permissions for a socket that was created inside a Docker container (which is where pppd is running) to be the same when the container is run on Centos8 as when it is run on Raspbian.

@n.m.couldbeanAI FWIW, binding to INADDR_ANY causes the socket to use eth0 as you might expect.

INADDR_ANY is a wildcard, that is, an address of all interfaces. If your server gets a packet from eth0, then the incoming packet was sent to the address of eth0. You can listen on other interfaces until cows come home and not hear anything,

You are also up against the TCP/IP ‘weak end system model’ here. Look it up.

Follow-up question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78301214/sufficient-permission-to-run-setsockopt-without-using-sudo.
