Sufficient permission to run setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, ...) without using sudo
This is a follow-up to Bind socket to interface using bind() v using setsockopt().
I need a (C) application to run setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, ...) in order to make a socket use a specific network interface.  I need to do this within an Ubuntu [5.15.76-v8+] Docker container that is running on top of either Raspbian [5.15.76-v8+] or Centos8 [4.18.0-408.el8.x86_64].
Ubuntu-on-Raspbian is fine, it just works, but with Ubuntu-on-Centos8 setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, ...) fails with errno EPERM (i.e. 1), "Operation not permitted".  I understand from this question that setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, ...) needs CAP_NET_RAW capability, however I can't just invoke sudo setcap on the executable I am running to fix it; this is a test system and all processes are run through non-interactive SSH by Jenkins: there is no terminal on which a password can be entered (and it would make no sense to do so), hence no sudo.
My QUESTION is: how do I make the Ubuntu-on-Centos8 case work?
FYI, the build of the application and the Docker container are both under my control.  The Docker container is run as a named user with membership of the right groups, rather than just being root.  In case it matters, the thing providing the network interface that I need to point the socket at is pppd (running inside the Docker container with setuid permissions).

Permissions depend on the specific option that's being set.

Most options don't require any special permissions. The ones that do should document the capabilities required.

@Barmar: post updated to include exact option being set.

https://github.com/constanze/GSoC2010_Gentoo_Capabilities/wiki/pam_cap-on-gentoo (should work on most any standard linux distro). You can also just set the setuid bit on your executable. But really, why are you testing this? Do you expect your customers to grant CAP_NET_RAW left and right? Maybe you need to set up routing correctly instead.

@n.m.couldbeanAI: thanks, I have followed those instructions, so /etc/pam.d/system-auth contains auth required pam_env.so and auth required pam_cap.so, and /etc/security/capability.conf contains cap_net_raw username (before none *), but getpcaps $$ still shows no user capabilities: does PAM even run in a Docker image?  Nothing is normally being authenticated after all.
FYI, our customers won't do this because they won't have another network interface, we only do it to stop our test system using its Ethernet interface rather than the PPP connection it is meant to test.

IMNSHO the proper way to resolve this is to set up a correct routing table. Create a dedicated testing network. Packets destined to that network should go to ppp0. No need to play with SO_BINDTODEVICE.

Maybe: we only need this for a single test out of many thousands, the Docker image we use during testing doesn't even have/need iptables (99.99% of it is on embedded MCUs; Linux gives us a nose bleed).  But perhaps I need to switch yaks :-).

Ah, but I guess I could just disable eth0!?  Sledgehammer time...

Confirmed that if I run ip link set down eth0 in the Docker container my aim is achieved (though I had to chmod 4755 /usr/sbin/ip in order to be able to run that as a non-root user).  For a test system, where security is no concern, this is a nice simple solution.
